# Two values from a single HTML checkbox

Tags: html

is it possible to have two values assigned to one checkbox? I require the checkbox to have the value yes or no and I'm simply wondering if this is possible to do with HTML. For example when the checkbox is checked it has the value of 'Yes' and unchecked it has the value of 'No' Thanks

EDIT:
Used a workaround that works fine in the PHP that handles the form if anyone else has this issue.

```
$var1 = e($_POST['checkbox']);
if ($var1 == null){
    $var = 'No';
}else{
    $var = 'Yes';
}
```

Comment: Where's your code? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

A checkbox has an attribute 'checked' which you can use to compute the value you need:

```
const checkbox = document.getElementById('my-checkbox');
const value = checkbox.checked ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought that might be the case, I decided to use a little workaround in the PHP that handles the form.

Answer (score 1):

No, your checkbox will have a value and if it's checked - that value will be submitted with the form, if it's not checked it won't be.

The only way you could have two values is if you had an "onChange" listener in javascript and toggle the value based on if it's checked or not.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that might be the case, I decided to use a little workaround in the PHP that handles the form.